# old woman, nanobots, crosslinked noodles, genetically engineered dog in a vest delivering a message

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, nanotechnology

Book is similar in style and elements to "The Diamond Age".  World demographics are mostly "old women".  They hold most of the wealth and most of the political power.  Young people have a hard time competing and/or establishing themselves.  There's nanobots, quick and easy travel, lots of single-use items crafted from atom-assemblers, and then recycled when no longer needed.  Our protagonist is an "Old Woman" who somehow becomes young again (nanobots, maybe?) She gets a boyfriend, gets a period, freaks out, and gets a wicked craving for some complicated, crosslinked noodles.  There's also a dog.  He's a genetically engineered messenger dog, who's job is to sniff her out and deliver a message.  She refuses the message, which upsets the dog, and makes people angry - because upsetting a delivery-dog is just, mean.

I swear this is really a book and not an acid flashback!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not have enough karma to comment, but could it be ['Holy Fire'](https://www.worldswithoutend.com/novel.asp?ID=81) by Bruce Sterling? As copied / pasted from the linked website:

> Mia Ziemann is a 94-year-old medical economist who enjoys all the benefits of her position. But a deathbed visit with a long-ago ex-lover and a chance meeting with a young bohemian dress-designer brings Mia to an awful revelation. She has lived her life with such caution that it has been totally bereft of pleasure and adventure. She has one chance to do it all over. But first she must submit herself to a radical--and painful--experimental procedure which promises to make her young again. The procedure is not without risk and her second chance at life will not come without a price. But first she will have to escape her team of medical keepers.

Comment: YES!  That is exactly it.  Thanks Derjoachim for scratching my brain-itch!

Comment: And a good thing you couldn't comment, because it meant you posted a good answer. :-)